# @material-extended/mde package has incompatible dependency error : While upgrading angular 11 to 12

Tags: angular-upgrade, angular12

Package "@material-extended/mde" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/animations" (requires "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0-0" (extended), would install "12.1.2").

Current Version :"@material-extended/mde": "^3.0.3",

Answer (score 1):

@material-extended/mde@3.0.3 is nog longer receiving updates. Either someone takes charge of that project and updates it, or you will need to replace your dependency with something else. Using --force is just postponing the point where this library breaks forever.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading `angular` from `11` to `12` using the following command:

```
ng update @angular/core --force
```

Or

```
ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12 --force
```